# Run Custom MYSQL query in AWS GLUE pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have use case where after inserting a row in mysql table i want to fetch back the id of the last inserted row. I wanted to run a MYSQL query in aws glue for the same. I am new to pyspark and wasn't able to find a whole lot for the same.Here is the code to connect to db.
My custom query

```
INSERT INTO users (name,email) VALUES ('abc1234','abc1234@gmail.com');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

# Create a SparkContext and GlueContext
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# Define your RDS database endpoint, username, and password
source_host = "xxx"
source_db = "xxx"
source_port = "3306"
source_driver = "jdbc"
source_db_type = "mysql"
source_user = "xxx"
source_password = "xxx"

# Define the JDBC URL
source_connection_url = f'{source_driver}:{source_db_type}://{source_host}:{source_port}/{source_db}'
source_table = "users"
source_connection_mysql5_options = {
    "url": source_connection_url,
    "dbtable": source_table,
    "user": source_user,
    "password": source_password
}
source_dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                        connection_type="mysql",connection_options=source_connection_mysql5_options)
source_dynamic_frame.printSchema().
```

Answer (score 0):

with mysql ucan create id with AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

And then you can use filter() of dynamicframe:

```
# Filter records based on the maximum value of a column
max_value = source_dynamic_frame.max('id')
filtered_dynamic_frame = dynamic_frame.filter(lambda x: x['id'] == max_value)
```

Comment: I know i can do it this way.Just wanted to check how i can run a mysql query here.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

check this : [Define connection options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc-home.html)

you can add `sampleQuery` attribute where you can add custom query.

**Solution 2:**(to be checked)

you can a specify your query in `dbtable` for example

```
source_connection_mysql_options = {
  "url": source_connection_url,
  "dbtable": "(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()) AS lastInserted",
  "user": source_user,
  "password": source_password
}
```

**Solution 3:**

Create Mysql View based on your custom query that you will use as source in Glue